# Are MFCC features required for speech recognition

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, feature-selection, mfcc

I'm currently developing a speech recognition project and I'm trying to select the most meaningful features.
Most of the relevant papers suggest using Zero Crossing Rates, F0, and MFCC features therefore I'm using those.
My question is, a training sample with duration of 00:03 has 268 features. Considering I'm doing a multi class classification project with 50+ samples per class training including all MFCC features may suffer the project from curse of dimensionality or 'reduce the importance' of the other features.
So my question is, should I include all MFCC features if not can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use f0 and zero crossing, they are too unstable. You can simply increase your training data and use mfccs, they have good representation capabilitites. But remember to mean-normalize them.

Comment: Are mfcc good only for speech or , can they be used for any audio/sound related task?

Comment: For some tasks MFCCs are ok, for some tasks like music recognition it is no enough resolution and other features are used.

Comment: About mean normalisation: do I do that per MFCC-bin? Or do I mean normalise over all MFCC-bins together? That is to say, is the relative values between bins of any importance so it should be avoided destroing it by separate normalisations per bin?

Answer (score 3):

After getting the MFCC coefficient of each frame, you can represent as MFCC features as the combination of:

```
 1) First 12 MFCC
 2) 1 energy  feature
 3) 12 delta MFCC feature
 4) 12 double-delta MFCC feature
 5) 1 delta energy feature
 6) 1 double delta energy feature
```

The concent of delta MFCC feature is described in this
 [link.](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/#deltas-and-delta-deltas)

The 39 dimension MFCC feature is feed into [HMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or  [Recurrent Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network).

Comment: What do you mean by 1 energy feature? Are you suggesting using the total energy, if that is the case the total energy is not a variable and has no delta.

Comment: 2 point energy refer to the energy for the signal x in a window from time sample t1 to t2.

Comment: As the delta MFCC also vary, 1 delta energy is the energy corresponds to that.

Comment: I'd say that this approach is very common for speech recognition. Note that it's not the first 12 CCs, it's #2-13 as the first is dropped, as it's equivalent to the energy feature.

Comment: @Someone by any chance do you have a github repo that shows how to feed these features to a ML model like RNN or HMM? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The point I'd like to make is that MFCCs are not required. You can use MFCCs, and you can use the energy, delta and delta-delta features, as mentioned by @Mahendra Thapa but it is not "required". Some researchers use 40 CCs, some drop the DCT from MFCC calculation making it MFSCs (spectral not cepstral). Some add extra features. Some use less. Susceptibility to the curse of dimensionality depends on the your classifier, doesn't it? Some recently even claim to have made progress towards the "holy grail" of speech recognition, to train using the raw signal, using deep learning, learning the best features rather than hand-crafting them.

Answer (score 0):

MFCC is widely used,and the effect is relatively better .

Comment: could you please expand on your answer

Comment: you can refer more articles which do researches on the principle and application of MFcc