# MFCC mean normalisation

Tags: speech-recognition, normalization, mfcc

Related to: [Are MFCC features required for speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833661/are-mfcc-features-required-for-speech-recognition/38878098#38878098)

Can the mean normalisation be reduced to simple mean subtraction of all the  (n,13) MFCCs and be used to train the data?

```
np.subtract(mfcc_feat,np.mean(mfcc_feat))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this is correct. Optionally, you can divide by variance as well.

Comment: Since there are large differences in the span of various mfcc-bins... Is normalisation on the whole analysis frame recommended over normalisation per mfcc-bin?

Comment: If we are talking about [CMVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstral_mean_and_variance_normalization) then it depends on the nature of your analysis. For example, for offline speech recognition (i.e. when the whole utterance is present before the recognition starts) the common practise is to do CMVN once. For online recognition, on the other hand, it's recommended to update the mean and the variance incrementally.

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm stil uncertain if that means that (say we have 13 mfcc:s) all coefficients (bins) are normalized in relation to the same mean/stddev (computed from all 13 mfcc:s in N frames or batches), or if the praxis is to normalize each mfcc in relation to it's own mean/stddev only. The linked article says "linearly transforming the cepstral coefficients to have the same segmental statistics." But I don't understand what they mean by that. The first mfcc is also often very large, which might need special treatment?

Comment: Ah, now I have got what you mean. In your case, the mean is going to be a 13-dimensional vector and you apply it to the MFCC vector componentwise.

Comment: Great, that was the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.